# How to send Email from XAMPP localhost

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, email, mysqli

I am trying to send email from localhost XAMPP, I have updated all the required files but still unable to send Email from localhost.

**php.ini**

```
sendmail_path = "\"D:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

**sendmail.ini**

```
smtp_port=587

auth_username=myemail@gmail.com
auth_password=mypassword
```

After all these update i have created a PHP file mail.php to send mails but its not delivering any Email.

```
            include 'connect.php';

            $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ; // Subject of your email
            $personal_email= "abc@hotmail.com";


            $message .= 'Name: ' . $_REQUEST['name'] . "<br>";
            $message .= $_REQUEST['product_type']. "<br>";
            $message .= $_REQUEST['message'];


            $subject_to_sender= "Confirmation";
            $message_to_sender = "Thanks for contacting us";



            $name=          $_REQUEST['name'];
            $email=         $_REQUEST['email'];
            $message=           $_REQUEST['message'];
            $product_type=      $_REQUEST['product_type'];
            $address=           $_REQUEST['address'];


    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: " . $_REQUEST['email'] . "\r\n"; // Sender's E-mail
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";    



        if (@mail($email, $subject_to_sender, $message_to_sender, $headers))
        {
            mail($personal_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
       // Transfer the value 'sent' to ajax function for showing success message.
            echo 'sent';
            }
```

On Send Button i also send all the Data into Database, and its successfully inserting data into database.

Kindly guide me.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost

Comment: No error, but its not sending mail as well